# comment layout like on Instagram

Tags: android

I would like to do the same behavior like comment layout on Instagram. So I've added this layout:

```
       <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/persistent_buttons_area_height"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.xxx.ui.widget.mention.AuthorMentionsEditText
                android:id="@+id/comment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/keyline_1"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/keyline_1"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/keyline_1"
                style="@style/ItemNewsFeedEditCommentMessage"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send"
                android:inputType="text|textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:hint="@string/news_feed_add_comment_hint" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:background="@color/theme_accent_3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/keyline_7"
                android:padding="12dp">

                <com.xxx.ui.widget.IconView
                    android:id="@+id/send_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/keyline_4"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/keyline_4"
                    app:iconFillColor="@color/text_2_secondary_color"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_check" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

The result is:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfSDb.png)

The blue area doesn't match with its parent. Normal, I set "wrap_content" constraint on "send" layout. So if I change by "match_parent", this is the behavior directly (without text!):

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzvtv.png)

So how can I do for having blue area ("send" layout) like Instagram?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="text|textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/send_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_round" />


</LinearLayout>
```

than set hight of a `ImageView` programmatically like this

```
comment= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment);
        imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.send_icon);

        comment.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                int hight=comment.getHeight();
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, hight);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

> **OUTPUT**

- **NORMAL**

[image]

- **when long text**

[image]

- **more long text**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the Screenshots of Layout

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/commentAddLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addcomment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp_3"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#4E8CF5"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp_20"
            android:src="@mipmap/tick"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can use this layout in your XML to make this type of layout like Instagram.

Answer (score 1):

No needed to use **External library**

**Just copy paste above snippet:** as u want line **instagram** comment BOX

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user31.demosforstack.CommentInstagram">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:hint="comment"
                android:padding="10dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#2698f8"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_right_mark" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output**

Simple without adding any text

[image]

after adding some text lines

[image]

adding much of lines

[image]

Hope it will helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Add Align top and baseline of send button with comment box, so it will fill the size

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/comment" //<---
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/comment"      // <----
    android:background="@color/theme_accent_3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/keyline_7"
    android:padding="12dp">

<com.xxx.ui.widget.IconView
    android:id="@+id/send_icon"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/keyline_4"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/keyline_4"
    app:iconFillColor="@color/text_2_secondary_color"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_check" />

</FrameLayout>
```